# Why my recursion solution for checking the balanced tree is not correct?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null)
            return true;
        int left = calculateDepth(root.left);
        int right = calculateDepth(root.right);

        int differ = left >= right ? left-right : right - left;
        if (differ<=1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int calculateDepth(TreeNode root){
        if (root == null)
            return 0;
        int left = calculateDepth(root.left);
        int right = calculateDepth(root.right);
        return (left == 0 || right == 0) ? left+right+1 : 1+Math.max(left,right);
    }
```

This is the leetcode110:  Balanced Binary Tree. 203 / 228 test cases passed. It failed in this case: [1,2,2,3,null,null,3,4,null,null,4]. I tested this case on Intellij, it works fine but it failed in leetcode. This is the code I used on Intellij Idea to test.

```
public class leetcode110 {
    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null)
            return true;
        int left = calculateDepth(root.left);
        int right = calculateDepth(root.right);

        int differ = left >= right ? left-right : right - left;
        if (differ<=1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int calculateDepth(TreeNode root){
        if (root == null)
            return 0;
        int left = calculateDepth(root.left);
        int right = calculateDepth(root.right);
        return (left == 0 || right == 0) ? left+right+1 : 1+Math.max(left,right);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode n1 = new TreeNode(1);
        TreeNode n2 = new TreeNode(2);
        TreeNode n3 = new TreeNode(2);
        TreeNode n4 = new TreeNode(3);
        TreeNode n5 = new TreeNode(3);
        TreeNode n6 = new TreeNode(4);
        TreeNode n7 = new TreeNode(4);
        n1.left = n2;
        n1.right=n3;
        n2.left=n4;
        n3.right=n5;
        n4.left=n6;
        n5.right=n7;

        leetcode110 sol = new leetcode110();
        System.out.println(sol.isBalanced(n1));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Leetcode it fails because the Test case input is wrong. In your example, you have used [1,2,2,3,null,null,3,4,null,null,4] which is not valid, you are missing an extra `null` value before the last `4` in your array.
So the correct array input is [1,2,2,3,null,null,3,4,null,null,`null`,4]

However, There are couple of improvement I would suggest

- There is no need call `calculate` function 2 times because main resurcive calls are made later.

Here is the updated code -

```
  private boolean result= Boolean.TRUE;
  public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
     calculateDepth(root);
     return result;
   }

    public int calculateDepth(TreeNode root){
        if (root == null)
            return 0;
        int left = calculateDepth(root.left);
        int right = calculateDepth(root.right);
        if(Math.abs(left - right) > 1)
            result= Boolean.FALSE;
        return 1+Math.max(left,right);
    }
```